# How do I add Date range criteria to email import?

Tags: excel, vba, date, import, outlook

I have some coding which imports several folders worth of stored emails into Excel. The coding brings back all stored emails from the folders.

I would like only the previous month's emails. I have formulas in place which are dynamic and automatically update the previous months start and end date. I know I need to reference these ranges within the coding.

I have defined ranges `Range("BOMD")` and `Range("EOMD")` - these are formula driven cells which calculate the first day and last day of the month respectively.

How would I add the date criteria to the below coding?

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olItem As Object
    Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim hdr As Variant
    Dim iFldr As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EmailImport")
    
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
     
    With ws
        iRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For iFldr = 1 To 18
        Select Case iFldr
            Case 1
                Set olFldr = olNS.Folders("test1").Folders("test1").Folders("test1")
                Set olFldr = olFldr.Folders("test1a")
            Case 2
                Set olFldr = olNS.Folders("test1").Folders("test1").Folders("test1")
                Set olFldr = olFldr.Folders("test1b")
                
            Case Else
        End Select

        For Each olItem In olFldr.Items
            If olItem.Class = olMail Then
                Set olMailItem = olItem
                With olMailItem
                    iRow = iRow + 1
                    If Not .Sender Is Nothing Then ws.Cells(iRow, "A") = .Sender
                    ws.Cells(iRow, "B") = .SenderEmailAddress
                    ws.Cells(iRow, "C") = .SenderName
                    ws.Cells(iRow, "D") = .Subject
                    ws.Cells(iRow, "E") = .ReceivedTime
                    ws.Cells(iRow, "F") = .Categories
                    ws.Cells(iRow, "G") = .TaskCompletedDate
                    ws.Cells(iRow, "H") = olFldr.Name
                End With
            End If
        Next olItem
    Next iFldr

    With ws
        hdr = Array("Sender", "SenderEmailAddress", "SenderName", "Subject", "ReceivedTime", "Categories", "TaskCompletedDate", "Folder")
        .Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(hdr)) = hdr
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You've said the date ranges update dynamically, where do you want to source the date for your code? Can it be sourced from some date values on your sheet? Will it need to be entered perhaps into an inputbox by the user? There are lots of answers to your question, but you will need to tell us what it is you are trying to do any how it's not working.

Comment: Yes - I have defined ranges Range("BOMD") and Range("EOMD") - these are formula driven cells which calculate the first day and last day of the month respectively. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the difference between when it was sent and when you are processing it:

```
Dim Difference As Long    
Difference = DateDiff("d", olItem.SentOn, Now)
If Difference < 30 Then
    ' Do Stuff
End If
```

If you want a date comparison this should be possible via an equality statement but make sure the dates are converted to CDate values beforehand

Answer (score 0):

You can create a restriction on the `ReceivedTime` property and pass it to `Items.Restrict` (which returns a new restricted `Items` collection:

```
([ReceivedTime] > '04/01/2021') AND ([ReceivedTime] < '04/21/2021')
```